# How to separate different values and make them variables

Tags: perl, bash, sed, awk, grep

Want to separate different values and make them variables:

```
db2
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION= (ADDRESS_LIST= (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=server1)(PORT=1521))) (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=db2))) OK (0 msec)
db1
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL= TCP)(Host= 10.1.1.1)(Port= 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME =db1))) TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
xdb3
TNS-03505: Failed to resolve name
```

Also OK to be renamed to active and when get any different result from that to get inactive like in the case is "TNS:no listener" or "TNS-03505: Failed to resolve name" and to add unkown string after it because don't have additional data.

Expected View:

```
db2,active,server1
db1,inactive,10.1.1.1
xdb3,inactive,unknown
```

Comment: So, what have you tried? Where are you stuck? It's not nice to just ask others to do your work from scratch. :(

Comment: So I perform this command:
`DB="xdb3 db1 db2";for x in $DB;do echo $x;tnsping $x|awk '{a[NR%2]=$0}END{for(i=NR+1;i<=NR+2;i++)print a[i%2]}'|sed '/^$/d'|sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g';done`

But stuck to make this result to variables separated with comma ...

Comment: solution doesn't work for you?

Comment: It's work for the previous situation but not work on the edit page

Comment: usually one should post a new question after it was accepted already

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I will turn the accept, but could you help me on the new one please ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
perl -ne 'chomp;push @r,$_}{ ($m)=$r[$_] =~ /host=\s*([^)]+)/i, print ("$r[$_-1],", $m? "active,$m\n":"inactive\n") for grep $_%2, 0..$#r;' logfile
```

modified version,

```
perl -ne 'chomp; if($. % 2){print "$_,";next;} ($m)=/host=\s*([^)]+)/i; print ((/\bOK\b/ ? "active," :"inactive,"), $m||"unknown","\n")' logfile
```

Comment: Thanks again and for advice, next time will create new post.
Get some error:
Undefined subroutine &main::say called at -e line 1, <> line 2.

Comment: I Get that: Unrecognized switch: -E  (-h will show valid options).

Comment: Yes, I use perl 5.8.8 but now get that output:
`db2,
active,
db1,
inactive,
xdb3,
inactive,` after every column everything is on the new row.

Comment: could you comment please?!

Comment: @KalinBorisov I had to make modification

Comment: That working great, thanks I really try some modifications but without success ...

Answer (score 2):

If you already use perl, I may suggest something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my $name;
while (<DATA>) {
  if ($. % 2) { chomp; ($name = $_)=~ s/\s+$//; next; }
  if (/HOST=([^)]+)/i) { print "$name,active,$1\n";
  } else { print "$name,inactive\n";
  }
}

__DATA__
db2    
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION= (ADDRESS_LIST= (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=server1)(PORT=1521))) (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=db2))) OK (0 msec)
db1    
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL= TCP)(Host= 10.1.1.1)(Port= 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = db1))) OK (0 msec)
xdb3
TNS-03505: Failed to resolve name
```

Output:

```
db2,active,server1
db1,active, 10.1.1.1
xdb3,inactive
```

Of course you should use the input file, instead of the `DATA` file handle.